# Criteria for a variable to be usable in a constant expression

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This code compiles just fine on all big 4 compilers, even on `-pedantic`

```
struct S
{
  constexpr S(int a) {}
};

constexpr int f(S a)
{
  return 1;
}

int main()
{
  int a = 0;
  S s(a);
  constexpr int b = f(s);
}
```

However, this shouldn't be so according to the standard... right? Firstly, `s` wouldn't be *usable in constant expressions* [[expr.const]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#3), because it fails to meet the criteria of being either `constexpr`, or, `const` and of enum or integral type.

Secondly, it is not *constant-initialized* [[expr.const]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2) because the full expression of the initialization would not be a *constant expression* [[expr.const]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#10) due to a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion being performed on a variable (`a`) that is not *usable in constant expressions*  when initializing the parameter of the constructor.

Are all these compilers just eliding the initialization of the parameter of the constructor because it has no side-effects, and is it standard conforming (I'm 99% sure it isn't, as the only way for it to so would be to make `s` `constexpr`, and to pass it either a `const int` or a `int` that is declared `constexpr`)?

Comment: Hm, your reasoning sounds plausible at least... The single point you *might* have overlooked is that `f` doesn't use the parameter `a` at all, so the result remains constexpr in any case. *If* I'm right here then compilation should fail if you store the parameter passed to `S`'s constructor in a yet to be added member variable and return that one from within `f`.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading things wrong, but why would there be an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of `a`? Arguments to functions (including constructors) are only implicitly converted (including value transformations) *if needed*. Passing an unqualified non-reference `int` to a function accepting an unqualified non-reference `int` as argument doesn't need any conversion or transformation at all, just a plain copy of the value.

Comment: @Aconcagua Correct, if the value is stored, it fails to compile, however, the parameter should be initialized (standard does not allow for the initialization to be elided)

Comment: This initialisation, as is, doesn't have any side effects, though. That might have some influence.

Comment: expr3: s is not used.
expr2: it's a local int. The compiler knows that value at compile time.
Compilers are smart.

Comment: @MFnx I'm more asking if this is well-formed in the eyes of the standard

Comment: If you add a data member and instead pass `S` by `const&`, [it still compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/Sjeebo) :P

Comment: @Rakete1111 yup, I figured it out. Not a *totally* equal comparison though, since the rules for references are more lax.

Answer (score 10):

I believe the magician's trick here is the copy c'tor of `S`. You omitted it, so a defaulted one is generated for you here. Now it's a `constexpr` function too.

> **[class.copy.ctor]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [12](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#12) A copy/move constructor that is defaulted and not defined as
>   deleted is *implicitly defined* when it is odr-used ([basic.def.odr]),
>   **when it is needed for constant evaluation** ([expr.const]), or when it
>   is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration. [ Note: The
>   copy/move constructor is implicitly defined even if the implementation
>   elided its odr-use ([basic.def.odr], [class.temporary]). — end note ]
>   **If the implicitly-defined constructor would satisfy the requirements
>   of a constexpr constructor ([dcl.constexpr]), the implicitly-defined
>   constructor is constexpr**.

Does the evaluation of the copy c'tor run afoul of any of the points in [[expr.const]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4)? It does not. It doesn't perform an lvalue to rvalue conversion on any of the argument's members (there are none to perform the conversion on). It doesn't *use* its reference parameter in any way that will require said reference to be usable in a constant expression. So we indeed get a valid constant expression, albeit a non-intuitive one.

We can verify the above by just adding a member to `S`.

```
struct S
{
  int a = 1;  
  constexpr S(int a) {}
};
```

Now the copy c'tor is trying to access an object that is not usable in a constant expression as part of its evaluation (via said reference). So indeed, [compilers will complain](https://godbolt.org/z/3AKXD8).

Comment: That still does not change the fact that `s` is not usable in constant expressions.

Comment: @KrystianS It looks like [\[expr.const\]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4) doesn't say you cannot *mention* a variable that is not usable in constant expressions in constant expressions ...

Comment: @KrystianS - But it doesn't *get* used. The copy c'tor is responsible for producing a value, and it does so without evaluating `s`.

Comment: @KrystianS Why? Copy ctor takes `S const&`; this needs no "evaluation". As log as it doesn't look at the object passed, it's fine to produce a fresh empty value which can be established in compile-time.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz This is more of a question of "is this well formed in the eyes of the standard". Of course, the compiler can just elide a good bit of this, but is it well-form by the wording of the standard?

Comment: @KrystianS My point is that having a ref parameter to an object that doesn't get used at all, and that object not coming from a constant expression, doesn't block the whole function from being a constant expression. That's kind of like having global variables but not using them.

Comment: @KrystianS The parameters are initialized from the arguments, and this initialization is `constexpr`.  That makes the expression a constant expression.

Comment: The standard still mandates that the id-expression is evaluated, and when evaluated it refers to an object that is not usable in a constant expression.

Comment: @KrystianS - *What* in the standard mandates that, pray tell?

Comment: @KrystianS Again, [\[expr.const\]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4) doesn't say you can't evaluate an id-expression denoting a variable that is not usable in constant expressions.  The concept "usable in constant expressions" is only used in the specification, and it doesn't mean anything by itself.  Forget about the name "usable in constant expressions", think about it just like any other predicate *P*.

Comment: @KrystianS That's about **references**.  Please reread it.  "an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member **of reference type** unless **the reference** has a preceding initialization and either ..."

Comment: @KrystianS - That refers to an id-expression that is a reference. The only reference here is the parameter of the copy c'tor. The implicitly defined copy c'tor in your case doesn't contain a use of that reference. It does however in the modified code, which is what helps trip the whole thing.

Comment: Under that interpretation, an id-expression denoting a variable of non-reference type would never be a core constant expression.

Comment: @KrystianS - No it doesn't mean that

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, it does, because the wording clearly states:

An expression e is a core constant expression **unless** the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following:
- **an id-expression that refers to a variable or** [...]

Comment: @KrystianS - or member **of a reference type**. Both variable and member are of a reference type here.

Comment: @L.F. Ah, ok, thats probably because http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#6 does the opposite thing :P

Comment: @KrystianS Interesting.  That sentence has an "of" in "of an object", so it is not ambiguous from a grammatical perspective I guess.

Comment: @StoryTeller @L.F. Figured it out now. The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion does not take place (typically doesn't for objects of class type) because `s` is bound to a reference (of the copy constructor), and the copy constructor call itself is a constant expression.

Comment: @KrystianS - Exactly!

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank you for clarifying that sentence to me, it make constant expressions make more sense :P